# Mapping values from one Dataframe to another and updating existing column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe

| Id | Name | Score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | 10 |
| 2 | Mary | 10 |
| 3 | Tom | 9 |
| 4 |  | 8 |
| 5 |  | 7 |

And another dataframe

| Id | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 4 | Jerry |
| 5 | Pat |

And I want a resulting dataframe like this

| Id | Name | Score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | 10 |
| 2 | Mary | 10 |
| 3 | Tom | 9 |
| 4 | Jerry | 8 |
| 5 | Pat | 7 |

Is there a way to do it in Python?

Comment: Where are you pulling the scores from for Jerry and Pat?

Comment: @CVerica the score exists in the original dataframe and it is just the name is missing and I have to pull it from another dataframe. It is mapped by the 'Id' column.

Answer (score 0):

Does this suffice:

```py
df1.set_index('Id').fillna({'Name' : df2.set_index('Id').Name}).reset_index()

   Id   Name  Score
0   1   John     10
1   2   Mary     10
2   3    Tom      9
3   4  Jerry      8
4   5    Pat      7
```